# SQL Returning Employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have 3 tables: Employee, Project, ProjectEmployee

- `Employee` has ID and Name
- `Project` has ID, Name, StartDate, EndDate
- `ProjectEmployee` has ID, EmployeeID, ProjectID

For example:

EMPLOYEE

```
    ID  |   Name
    ----+-------
    1   |   Amy 
    2   |   Ben 
    3   |   Charlie
```

PROJECT

```
    ID  |   Name    |   StartDate   |   EndDate
    ----+-----------+---------------+--------------
    1   |   P01     |   1-Jan-17    |   1-Feb-17
    2   |   P02     |   2-Feb-17    |   20-Feb-17
    3   |   P03     |   15-Mar-17   |   31-Mar-17
    4   |   P04     |   30-Nov-17   |   30-Dec-17
```

PROJECTEMPLOYEE

```
    ID  |   EmployeeID  |   ProjectID
    ----+---------------+-------------
    1   |       1       |   1
    2   |       1       |   2
    3   |       1       |   3
    4   |       1       |   4
    5   |       2       |   1
    6   |       2       |   2
    7   |       3       |   1
```

I want to create a query to find out the total returning employees who worked in a project. For example, there are 3 employees who worked in P01, but only 2 employees worked in subsequent projects within 180 days after the P1's EndDate (comparing one project's EndDate to next projects' StartDates)

For example:

- for Project P01, the subsequent projects within 6 months are P02 and P03
- for Project P02, the subsequent projects within 6 months is P03
- for Project P03, the subsequent projects within 6 months is none

Result should be listing all projects with their total number of employees and total number of returning employees count:

```
    Project |   TotalEmployees  |   TotalReturningEmployees
    --------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------
    P01     |       3           |   2   (Both Amy and Ben returning)
    P02     |       2           |   1   (Only Amy worked in P03)
    P03     |       1           |   0   (Amy worked in P04, but it's not within 6 months after P03 ended)   
    P04     |       1           |   0
```

Since I'm a novice at SQL, I tried working this problem with MS Access. Here's what I've got so far, this works but only showing one project.

```
SELECT SelectedProject AS Project,
       COUNT(*) AS ReturningEmployees
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ProjectEmployee.EmployeeID
    FROM Project
        INNER JOIN ProjectEmployee
            ON Project.ID = ProjectEmployee.ProjectID
    WHERE (
              (ProjectEmployee.EmployeeID IN (
                                                 SELECT ProjectEmployee.Employeeid
                                                 FROM ProjectEmployee
                                                 WHERE ProjectEmployee.Projectid = SelectedProject
                                             )
              )
              AND ((Project.StartDate)
          BETWEEN
                  (
                      SELECT Project.EndDate FROM Project WHERE Project.id = SelectedProject
                  ) AND (
                  (
                      SELECT Project.EndDate FROM Project WHERE Project.id = SelectedProject
                  ) + 180
                        )
                  )
          )
) AS Returning;
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" service. Show what you've tried and perhaps someone can offer some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This query can do the job

```
SELECT p3.ID,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProjectEmployee p1 WHERE p1.pid = p3.pid
  ), 
  COUNT(p2.pid)
FROM Project p3
LEFT JOIN ProjectEmployee p2 ON p2.ProjectID = p3.ID and p2.EmployeeID IN
  (
    SELECT pe.EmployeeID 
    FROM ProjectEmployee pe 
    WHERE pe.StartYear <= DateAdd(month, 6, p3.EndDate)
  )
GROUP BY p3.ID
```